# Creating a dictionary {names : list of values} from this .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .txt file that has names followed by numbers. For Example

```
namesToRatings = {}

with open("example.txt") as document:
    for line in document:
        print(line)
```

Would output:

```
Simon

5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 
0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 

John

5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 
-3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0
```

and so on...

How do I create a dictionary with the key being the name of the person and the value being a list of the numbers following that name?

E.g {Simon : [5, 0, 0, 0, 0,......... 5, 5, -5]

Comment: Read line by line, if line is filled and contains a-z remeber line content as key, read next lines , if line empty skip it, if line contains number, put it with last remembered key in dict. done

Comment: My bad - Simons entry would end in 5,5-5, Johns would end in 3,0,0

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("example.txt") as document:
    lines = [line for line in document if len(line.strip())]
    namesToRatings = {lines[i] : lines[i+1].split(" ") for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)}
    print(namesToRatings)  # print it, return it from a function, or set it as a global if you really must.
```

Comment: `if len(line)` == `if line` - better would probably be `if line.rstrip()`

Comment: `NameError: name 'line' is not defined` and if you change it to `lines` - `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I get NameError: name 'line' is not defined when i run this

Comment: @user8899578 Is it a name followed by any number of lines of numbers, or a name followed by a single line of numbers?

Comment: @user8899578 yes, i see how that error crept in, i changed `line` to `lines` now.

Comment: @John When I print the dictionary there is always a \n at the end of each key and value e.g {'john\n':['5','2','1'....'\n'],... }Do you know how I can get rid of this?

Comment: @user8899578 sure, I changed the end of the second line yesterday to `if len(line.strip())]` to deal with ambiguous line specification. It will strip that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/3r6KN9/1):

```
import re

di={}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for m in re.finditer(r'^([a-zA-Z]+)\s+([-\d\s]+)', f.read(), re.M):
        di[m.group(1)]=m.group(2).split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the get_close_matches on the difference library.

Save the dictionary words and meanings in a JSON file, then it will be in the Form of a python dictionary.

```
import json

from difflib import get_close_matches


data=json.load(open('filePath'))

def check_word(word) :
        word=word.lower()
         for word in data:
         return data
         If len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys(), cutoff=0.7))>0:
          return get_close_matches(word, data.keys(), cutoff=0.7)
```

> You can add more exceptions here...

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("example.txt") as document:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in document)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)
    pairs = zip(*[lines]*2)
    namesToRatings = {name: [int(x) for x in values.split()] for name, values in pairs}
```

This version is similar to the list based approach outlined in John's answer, but doesn't require reading the entire file into a list.  The `zip(*[lines]*2)` will split the input (the lines) into pairs.  Output:

```
{
 'Simon': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, -3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, -5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, -5], 
 'John': [5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 0, 3, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, -3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 3, 0, 0]
}
```